# Update 1 XML another another

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, compare

Hello: I changed the logic a little bit on this. The first Sub1 is match against field but only when field1 value match. The sub2 is only matching against field But  does not have multiple values. Would you please let me know if this is possible? Thank You!

```
<ROOT>
    <OLD>
        <sub1>
            <Row>
                <field1>1</field1>
                <field2>THING1</field2>
                <field3/>
                <field4/>
                <field5/>
                <field6/>
                <field7/>
            </Row>>
        <Row>
                <field1>2</field1>
                <field2>THING2</field2>
                <field3/>
                <field4/>
                <field5/>
                <field6/>
                <field7/>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <field1>3</field1>
                <field2>THING3</field2>
                <field3/>
                <field4/>
                <field5/>
                <field6/>
                <field7/>
            </Row>
        </sub1>
        <sub2>
            <field1>BeforeTEST</field1>
            <field2>That</field2>
            <field3/>
            <field4/>
            <field5/>
            <field6/>
            <field7/>
            <field8/>
            <field9/>
            <field10/>
            <field11/>
            <field12/>
            <field13/>
            <field14>Leave it</field14>
        </sub2>
    </OLD>
    <NEW>
        <sub1>
            <field1>1</field1>
            <field2>THING</field2>
            <field3>Is bad</field3>
        </sub1>
        <sub2>
            <field1>TEST</field1>
            <field2>THIS</field2>
            <field5>THAT</field5>
        </sub2>
    </NEW>
</ROOT>
```

How to get it to

```
<ROOT>
        <sub1>
            <Row>
                <field1>1</field1>
                <field2>THING</field2>
                <field3>Is bad</field3>
                <field4/>
                <field5/>
                <field6/>
                <field7/>
            </Row>>
        <Row>
                <field1>2</field1>
                <field2>THING2</field2>
                <field3/>
                <field4/>
                <field5/>
                <field6/>
                <field7/>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <field1>3</field1>
                <field2>THING3</field2>
                <field3/>
                <field4/>
                <field5/>
                <field6/>
                <field7/>
            </Row>
        </sub1>
        <sub2>
        <Row>
            <field1>TEST</field1>
            <field2>THIS</field2>
            <field3/>
            <field4/>
            <field5>THAT</field5>
            <field6/>
            <field7/>
            <field8/>
            <field9/>
            <field10/>
            <field11/>
            <field12/>
            <field13/>
            <field14>Leave it</field14>
            </Row>
        </sub2>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "update"? XSLT alone does not modify the source document/s.

Comment: Not Update.. simply create resulting XML with expect information as an output.

Comment: Okay, then. But did you just change the input to a **single file**? That would make a very big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that the names of `<sub1>`, `<sub2>`, etc. will **not** be known in advance. Still, if you can trust the basic structure of `ROOT/OLD/*/*` and a corresponding `ROOT/NEW/*/*`, you could do it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="update" match="NEW/*/*" use="concat(name(parent::*), '/', name())" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OLD">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OLD/*/*[key('update', concat(name(parent::*), '/', name()))]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('update', concat(name(parent::*), '/', name()))"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NEW"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that the more you know about the XML structure in advance, the more explicit you can be when selecting/matching nodes - and the more efficient the transformation process will be.

Comment: Hello Michael. That was awesome, thank you. To throw a ranch into the situation. if sub1 segment repeat multiple times and need to match only when field1 value from old and new are the same.

Comment: Hello Michael.. I just update the original post.. It is getting a lot more complex than I originally through. And I really do appreciate your help on this! Thank you!

Comment: @user3379902 Are you sure that is the exact structure? It doesn't seem consistent. It's also very difficult to understand the logic behind the transformation (assuming there is such logic).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your base file is used as source to the XSLT processor, and a file called `update.xml` contains the replacement fields, the stylesheet below can be used to replace the fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="update-doc" select="document('update.xml')"/>    
    <xsl:template match="/Root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Root/*">
        <xsl:variable name="sub-name" select="name(.)"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:variable name="base-field" select="."/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:if test="not($update-doc/Root/*[name() = $sub-name]/*[name() = name($base-field)])">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:for-each select="$update-doc/Root/*[name() = $sub-name]/*">
                        <xsl:variable name="replacement-field" select="."/>
                        <xsl:if test="name($base-field) = name($replacement-field)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$replacement-field"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If a field exists in the base document and does not exist in the update document, it will be preserved, otherwise it will be overriden.

**UPDATE** Since you changed your requirements and now you expect to have the data in one file, I adapted the stylesheet for your new format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/Root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|OLD"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OLD/*">
        <xsl:variable name="sub-name" select="name(.)"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[ancestor::OLD]">
                <xsl:variable name="base-field" select="."/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:if test="not(//NEW/*[name() = $sub-name]/*[name() = name($base-field)])">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:for-each select="//NEW/*[name() = $sub-name]/*">
                        <xsl:variable name="replacement-field" select="."/>
                        <xsl:if test="name($base-field) = name($replacement-field)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$replacement-field"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```